# Is it secure to use UDP socket communication for a game?

Tags: android, sockets, unity-game-engine, server, udp

I'm working on a multiplayer android game with Unity. For server side I use python. There is no login system or username. Basically, there is a matchmaking system and rooms. I send JSON object which contains room key, position of user and etc. from client to server. Room keys are unique and 10 digit hexadecimal numbers. I use UDP socket for communication.

1. Is it secure to only use a UDP socket for gameplay? Clients already have source code and can change it easily. So they can change data that coming from client to server. Do I need to implement an algorithm to make more secure from hack or cheat? Can anybody change the apk file and ruin everything in this game?
2. Can I use a port(eg. 8000) for both TCP and UDP connection where TCP accepts user/player for matchmaking and creates a unique room key to send client when server is ready? After client gets key, server will decide which user in which room with that room key or using UDP even at the matchmaking. Does this method make server slow?

Comment: This question should really be two different questions. I'm editing your post to remove the second one.

Comment: @Ruzihm, sorry, I restored the second question, as it was answered.

Answer (score 1):

> 1- Is it secure only using udp socket for gameplay. Clients already has source code and can change it easily. So they can change data that coming from client to server. Do I need implement an algorithm to make more secure from hack or cheat? Can anybody change apk file and ruin everything in this game?

UDP itself doesn't give you any reliance as default, so if you use UDP and need some reliance or guarantee of data arrival, you will need to implement acknowledgement logic into your protocol, with this will be possible avoid packet replication.

About security, yes you will need to implement handshaking, compression, and cryptography logic, and will need to use checksum algorithms to ensure the data to be parsed is not corrupted.  You will also need to implement some memory management logic on clients to make the communication between client and server not easily mappable by memory dumping to avoid cheating by memory overwriting.

> 2- Can I use a port(eg. 8000) for both tcp and udp connection where tcp is accept user/player for matchmaking and create a unique room key to sent client when server is ready. After client gets key, server will decides which user in which room with that room key or using udp even at the matchmaking. Is this method makes server slow?

You can use user ports that should be the range of 1024-49151.

Most great network mechanisms for games use TCP and UDP together and some techniques of throttling to keep synchronization between client and server. A good reading for you should be this post:

https://gafferongames.com/post/udp_vs_tcp/

Hope it helps.